# Scroll in terminal while Vim is running

Tags: vim, terminal, scrolling

When I open vim in some terminals (on mac for example) and use the mouse scroll, I am able to see the terminal output again.

If my terminal window would look like this:

```
user@pc$ "I'm gonna start vim" 
user@pc$ "after this line"
user@pc$ vim
```

I would like to see all these lines if I scroll up with the mouse scroll (in vim).

**Additional info if necessary:** 
I'm using xfce4-terminal 0.6.3 on Xubuntu 14.04 with Vim 7.4.52

Comment: Have you tried `:set mouse=a`?

Comment: yes, this only makes it possible to scroll down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that this emulates the behavior

```
" Might as well use 'r' 'v' instead of 'a'
:set mouse=a
:map <ScrollWheelUp> :!<CR>
```

The only downside is selecting with mouse, copy pasting does not work so use `:!` instead, if you don't want this.